# Delete part of name of multiple files in Linux

Tags: bash

I have several fastq.gz files in a directory. I want to delete parts of each file name. Here are the file names

```
RES-1448-001_S289_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
RES-1448-001_S289_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
RES-1448-012_S300_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
RES-1448-012_S300_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

I want to remove S and 3 digits after it and L001. I expect this after removing

```
RES-1448-001_R1_001.fastq.gz
RES-1448-001_R2_001.fastq.gz
RES-1448-012_R1_001.fastq.gz
RES-1448-012_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: ${thefilename:1:13} ${thefilename:24:15} if you filenames are in that exact type of format you have shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `bash` parameter expansion:

```
for file in *.fastq.gz; do
    start=${file%%_*}  ## Gets only the portion before first `_`
    end=${file#*_*_*_*}  ## Gets the portion after 3 `_`s from start
    echo mv -- "$file" "${start}_${end}"
done
```

This will just `echo` the `mv` command will be run, if satisfied remove the `echo` for actual `mv`-ing action:

```
for file in *.fastq.gz; do
    start=${file%%_*}
    end=${file#*_*_*_*}
    mv -- "$file" "${start}_${end}"
done
```

Comment: how to select the portion before first 3 '-'

Comment: @Bala Could you please ask this as a new question?

Comment: New question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41481847/remove-part-of-name-of-multiple-files-in-linux?noredirect=1

Answer (score -1):

With `perl`:

```
perl -ape 's{_S\d\d\d_L001}{}'
```