# Remove part of name of multiple files in Linux

Tags: bash

I have several fastq.gz files in a directory. I want to delete parts of each file name.

Here are the file names:

```
RES_1448_001_S289_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
RES_1448_001_S289_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
RES_1448_012_S300_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
RES_1448_012_S300_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

I want to remove S and 3 digits after it. I expect this after removing

```
RES_1448_001_R1_001.fastq.gz
RES_1448_001_R2_001.fastq.gz
RES_1448_012_R1_001.fastq.gz
RES_1448_012_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

I asked a similar question before, but was advised to ask a new one to cover the precise requirements I have now.

Old question: [Delete part of name of multiple files in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40757485/delete-part-of-name-of-multiple-files-in-linux)

Comment: And what have you already tried? What errors are you getting? Please show your work. SO is not a free coding website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rename`.

`rename 's/S\d{3}_//' *.fastq.gz`

Answer (score 1):

Using this `bash`, `regEx` would do the trick for you.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.fastq.gz
do
    if [[ $file =~ ^(.*)S([[:digit:]]{3})_L([[:digit:]]{3})_(.*)$ ]]
    then
        start="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        end="${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
        mv -- "$file" "${start}${end}"
    fi 
done
```